# Gatling Frontline incrementConcurrentUsers query - do aws auto-scaling testing on Microservice

Tags: gatling

I will appreciate your advice here:

- I am using Gatling as a performance tool.
- I need to test (on AWS account) Microservice including auto-scaling configuration
- in that case, I try to do something like that:

  ***scn.inject(
  incrementConcurrentUsers(20)
  .times(120)
  .eachLevelLasting(150 seconds)
  .separatedByRampsLasting(50 seconds)
  .startingFrom(20)
  )andThen(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(300).during(30 minutes)))***

by running the first setup i am getting good resoult and it will see like that:
[image]

BUT when this line added ***andThen(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(300).during(30 minutes))***

my result will be looking like that:
[image]

- but it did not work for me.
- my goal is to Incremental the load for a few hours to validate the service scaling and after that you continue with the max load till the end of the test.
  thanks

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on "it did not work for me".

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use different load models that are incompatible with eachother.

`incrementConcurrentUsers` belongs to the closed model

`constantUsersPerSec` belongs to the open model

It is important to distinguish which model is preferred for your application and use cases. The Gatling team published a [great article](https://gatling.io/2018/10/gatling-3-closed-workload-model-support/) outlining the differences between the models.

---

Let's return to the load profile. From the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/injection/#sequential-scenarios) we can see that `andThen` is used to chain *different* scenarios in a sequential way. In your case we're dealing with one scenario. Therefore I recommend to use only one injector. You can use [Meta DSL](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/injection/#meta-dsl) to create step-like behavior as follows:

```
setUp(
      scn.inject(
        incrementUsersPerSec(10)
          .times(5)
          .eachLevelLasting(3 minute)
          .separatedByRampsLasting(1 minute)
          .startingFrom(20),

        constantUsersPerSec(75) during (40 minutes)
      ).protocols(protocol)
    )
```